# Is there a word for letters that are shaped the same when capitalized or not?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, orthography, capitalization, shapes

The letters

c/C, o/O, s/S, v/V, w/W, x/X, z/Z

Are roughly congruently shaped from uppercase to lowercase. Depending on the font, there can be some serif differences but generally they have much less variance than say a/A or r/R etc.

Is there a word for this specifically?

Comment: I don’t have one word but maybe . . . *case-insensitive glyphs*.

Answer (score 6):

You could use **[isomorphic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/isomorphic#:%7E:text=Medical%20Definition-,isomorphic,form%20or%20shape%20or%20structure)**, but it's not specific to this particular example of similarity in shape. Merriam-Webster definition:

> being of identical or similar form, shape, or structure

Comment: I suppose you could say ***calligraphically isomorphic***

Comment: @FumbleFingers glyphically isomorphic?

Comment: There is another possibility:  'homeomorphic', which would, by derivation, mean of the same or a similar form.  The Cambridge English dictionary says "homeomorphic isn’t in the Cambridge Dictionary yet. You can help!".  It then gives examples of its use (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/603336/is-there-a-word-for-letters-that-are-shaped-the-same-when-capitalized-or-not).  The homeo- bit is from the Greek 'homoios', meaning 'same' or 'similar', where the 'iso-' bit of 'isomorphic' means 'equal'.  It raises the question of when a word is used enough to get into a dictionary.

Comment: *glyphically isomorphic*

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't such a single English word as you ask for.

Comment: How do you know? There might be an obscure typographers' or calligraphers' term, for instance.

Comment: If there is, what is it?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes, that is indeed the question posed.